# Intel TBB parallel_for vs pipeline

Tags: c++, multithreading, optimization, intel

I have a task at hand which conceptually simplifies to adding a constant number to each element in a 13M element, 25MB-sized array which does not fit into the cache 20MB in size. Thus my implementation is a for loop iterating through array indices. I used Intel Threading Building Block (TBB) to parallelize the task on an Intel Xeon E series server with the following spec:

`20 CPUs`
`Sandy Bridge Micro-architecture` 
`32K L1D, 256K L2, 20M L3`

There are two possible parallelization schemes. On the one hand, I can implement this using the parallel_for template function in Intel TBB, in which the Block_range object assists in breaking the array into chunks. On the other hand, I can choose to manually breaking the array into chunks and call each of the chunks a task, which can be passed to TBB's pipeline pattern.

To my surprise, the execution time measured using Oprofile under fixed chunk size of 10000 (about L2 cache size) for both implementations differ significantly. The simpler parallel_for function processed at 200MB/s while the more complex pipeline pattern processed at 600MB/s. Varying grain_size (1,000,000 to 10, with decrement of a factor of 10 each time.) for parallel_for does not vary the data processing rate much. Varying chunk_size for pipeline pattern changes the processing rate and these changes can be correlated with the sizes of L1, L2 and L3 caches.

Am I using parallel_for with a wrong grain_size? Or is pipeline inherently faster than parallel_for? Is it generally recommended to use parallel_for or pipeline when both manually and automatically segmenting the array are possible? What are the advantages and disadvantages of replacing parallel_for with pipeline?

Thanks,
Gu

Comment: Even 600MB seems awfully slow. Adding a constant to every element of an array is easily vectorized, meaning you should be memory-bound, and memory bandwidths are on the order of GB/sec.

Comment: I highly suspect your bottleneck is somewhere else. If adding a constant to an array is the only thing you are doing you should see much higher bandwidths. What's the bandwidth you get with no parallelization at all?

Comment: The function object does not just "add a constant" but goes through a series of arithmetic manipulations. When task scheduler is set to 1 thread only with tbb::task_scheduler_init init(1), the bandwidth is 90MB/s. All above figures were measured with no optimization from the gcc compiler.

Comment: The manipulations can be thought of as applying series of masks to an image.